# Can ICU convert codes 1-31 in CP 850?

Tags: c, icu

I need to convert from UTF-8 to CP 850, and would like to support as many different combinations as possible, for example accented characters as well as normal character plus combining diacritic.

Right now I am trying to find out if ICU handles the codes 1-31 (possibly except 9, 10, 13) in CP 850. Will they be the graphical symbols or will they be ASCII control codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition what you're talking about are control codes and are mapped as such by the Unicode specification to U+0001..U+001F (1..31). See the [ICU Converter Explorer](https://ssl.icu-project.org/icu-bin/convexp?conv=ibm-850_P100-1995&s=IBM) for example.

If you wanted the graphical representations instead, you'd need to find the graphical representations' Unicode equivalent and convert each code point yourself.

Comment: Well if you look here for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850#/media/File:Codepage-850.png the graphical symbols are the default. It says "code points 1–31 and 127 may be either ASCII control characters or code page 437 graphics, depending on context".

Comment: @TomasBy The source cited by that quote continues, "For displays the hexadecimal code in a memory-mapped video display buffer is a graphic. For printers the graphics context is established by a preceding control sequence in the data stream." In other words, if these control codes are for display, then they are unprocessed unless you (or your terminal driver) process them yourself, but the control codes are processed specially if they are used in printing. An application working with such control codes should handle them specially when dealing with printers.

Comment: For example, the `ESC` and `SOH` sequences (ASCII 0x1B and 0x01) could be a part of a control sequence ordinarily, but you could use `1B 5C 02 00 1B 01 0D 0A` to print the graphical versions, followed by `\r\n` (Carriage Return and Line Feed). However, this doesn't work for displays because they're always in "Print all characters" mode, from the perspective of a printer.